# os.walk creates a kernel panic

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, osx-mountain-lion

The directory I'm trying to walk has about 400k files in it according to

```
$ find . -type f | wc -l
```

Every time I run the script that uses `os.walk`, it sends my laptop into a kernel panic. It's very consistent.

OSX Mountain Lion, Python 2.7.4.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Example code

```
import os


def collect_files_for_path(path):
    all_files = []

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):

        for f in files:
            full = os.path.join(root, f)
            all_files.append(full)

    return all_files


files = collect_files_for_path('some/path')
```

**EDIT 2**: panic log

```
Tue Apr 23 11:17:22 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff800d4ee9a5): "hfs_lock: locking against myself!"@/SourceCache/xnu/xnu-2050.22.13/bsd/hfs/hfs_cnode.c:1751
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff813aca3390 : 0xffffff800d21d626
0xffffff813aca3400 : 0xffffff800d4ee9a5
0xffffff813aca3430 : 0xffffff800d518563
0xffffff813aca34b0 : 0xffffff800d3127ff
0xffffff813aca3500 : 0xffffff800d309001
0xffffff813aca3540 : 0xffffff800d32584c
0xffffff813aca35f0 : 0xffffff800d325ee5
0xffffff813aca3780 : 0xffffff800d511279
0xffffff813aca37b0 : 0xffffff800d4fc953
0xffffff813aca3830 : 0xffffff800d312a21
0xffffff813aca38c0 : 0xffffff800d2daa5e
0xffffff813aca39b0 : 0xffffff800d312a7e
0xffffff813aca39e0 : 0xffffff800d2dc68c
0xffffff813aca3a10 : 0xffffff800d2dc7e7
0xffffff813aca3a30 : 0xffffff800d5177d0
0xffffff813aca3a80 : 0xffffff800d312410
0xffffff813aca3ab0 : 0xffffff800d2eac05
0xffffff813aca3b50 : 0xffffff800d2ea1a4
0xffffff813aca3c10 : 0xffffff800d304a32
0xffffff813aca3d90 : 0xffffff800d2fd40c
0xffffff813aca3f50 : 0xffffff800d5e063a
0xffffff813aca3fb0 : 0xffffff800d2cdd23

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: Python

Mac OS version:
12D78

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.3.0: Sun Jan  6 22:37:10 PST 2013; root:xnu-2050.22.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 3EB7D8A7-C2D3-32EC-80F4-AB37D61492C6
Kernel slide:     0x000000000d000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff800d200000
System model name: MacBookPro8,1 (Mac-94245B3640C91C81)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 299018314244
last loaded kext at 77719537176: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp 4.2.1 (addr 0xffffff7f8ef2b000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 182522584862: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.2.5 (addr 0xffffff7f8dbf3000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.2.1
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.2.1
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.2.1
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.2.1
org.pqrs.driver.PCKeyboardHack  8.0.0
org.pqrs.driver.KeyRemap4MacBook    8.0.0
com.radiosilenceapp.nke.PrivateEye  1
com.Logitech.Unifying.HID Driver    1.2.0
com.Logitech.Control Center.HID Driver  3.5.1
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.1.3f3
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.87
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.7fc4
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.3.0
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.1.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.1.3f3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.3d0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.11
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.3d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 237.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.5.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   614.20.16
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.0b1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC  1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.5.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.1.3f3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.7fc4
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.11d0
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.1.3f3
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.3.0d51
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 237.3
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.9
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    296.16
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.3
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   522.4
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.5.5
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220.2
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 345
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.3
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
```

Comment: And maybe also some relevant kernel logs, if any?

Comment: @LevLevitsky Sure, I'd love to. Where can I find those?

Comment: @HonzaPokorny Not sure, never used OSX. In fact, I'm not sure that your question is a programming problem. Don't be surprised if your question if migrated somewhere. But I added tags to help OSX folks notice it here.

Comment: @LevLevitsky Thanks, I managed to find the log and have added it to the question.

Comment: Could not reproduce- have you tried running your script on smaller directories? How large does a directory have to be for the panic to happen?

Comment: @DavidRobinson 100k crashes it, about 500 doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be able to panic a system just by doing an os.walk.

You probably should fsck your filesystem (while unmounted) and check the disk for bad blocks.

Comment: I have checked and repaired the disk. The panics haven't stopped.

Answer (score 2):

If `find` is happy to 'walk' the directory, it seems more likely that the problem is building that huge list (`all_files`) in memory, which could easily be taking up 4-8GB of RAM.

Does the problem still occur if you remove the line...

```
all_files.append(full)
```

...and is there any reason you need to build a complete list, rather than doing whatever you intend to do with that list using the iterator returned by `os.walk()`?

**Update**

> Printing the paths alone will send the system into a kernel panic.

Very strange. If it always fails after printing the same filename, that might give you a clue as to which file is causing the problem.

Otherwise, the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/py3k/lib-python/2.7/os.py?#cl-209) for `os.walk()` is pretty simple, and written in pure Python, so if you made a copy of that code in a new file, and added some debug messages, it might help to track down the problem.

Ultimately, though, no user process should be able to cause a kernel panic, making this an OSX bug, so you might have more luck contacting Apple customer services - they actually get paid to solve these sorts of problems. ;-)

Comment: Printing the paths alone will send the system into a kernel panic.

Comment: `os.walk` returns a generator function so how could it be heavy on the ram? Last time I remember walking over a network drive which might easily have more files then that. Kept it walking overnight without any problem.

Comment: @hus787 You're correct that `os.walk()` is a generator, but the OP's code appends all the files to a list called `all_files`.

Comment: @Aya Ah! Correct, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Your python code is not causing the kernel panic.  Kernel panics on macs happen for a very small number of reasons:

1. Hardware problems
2. Bugs in the OS itself
3. Bugs in installed kernel drivers

Python doesn't install kernel drivers, so even though it's consistent, the root cause is something below your python code.

I see virtualbox in your panic trace.  That's probably your problem.  Here's a page describing how to read panic logs: http://www.embracingchaos.com/2011/05/macbook-crashes-kernel-panics-and-coping-with-an-apple-genius.html